# Using PyCharm and setup.py with packages with period in them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, setuptools

I am using PyCharm to generate a `setup.py` file for my project. The following file is generated:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='untitled',
    version='',
    packages=['venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.PyQt5', 'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.PyQt5.uic',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.PyQt5.uic.Loader', 'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.PyQt5.uic.port_v2',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.PyQt5.uic.port_v3',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.PyQt5.uic.Compiler', 'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.py2app',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.py2app.recipes', 'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.py2app.recipes.PIL',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.py2app.bootstrap', 'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.py2app.converters',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.py2app.apptemplate',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.py2app.bundletemplate', 'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.altgraph',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.macholib', 'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.modulegraph',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip.req',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip.vcs',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip.utils',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip.compat',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip.models',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.distlib',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.distlib._backport',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.colorama',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.html5lib',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.html5lib._trie',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.html5lib.filters',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.html5lib.treewalkers',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.html5lib.treeadapters',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.html5lib.treebuilders',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.lockfile',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.progress',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.requests',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.requests.packages',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.requests.packages.chardet',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.util',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.contrib',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.packages',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.packaging',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.cachecontrol',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.cachecontrol.caches',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.webencodings',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip._vendor.pkg_resources',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip.commands',
              'venv.lib.python3.6.site-packages.pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg.pip.operations'],
    url='',
    license='',
    author='',
    author_email='',
    description=''
)
```

The period in `python3.6` is causing problems because when I run `python setup.py develop` I get the following error:

```
error: package directory 'venv/lib/python3/6/site-packages/PyQt5' does not exist
```

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this? If I simply change the `python3.6` to `python36` it just further breaks everything. How do I fix this?

Project view:

[image]

Project structure:

[image]

Comment: I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem here - the real issue is that your project structure in Pycharm must be wrong. You never have to include anything from the python installation or `site-packages` directory in your `setup.py`. Did you include the complete venv directory in your project? The venv should be listed in `External libraries` and not be part of a project.

Comment: Did you delete your answer?

Comment: Yes, as you have not added `venv` to content roots, so the answer is useless. I have added your pics to the question, though.

Comment: Ok thanks. I presume then you have no idea what's wrong?

Comment: Your PyCharm configuration is wrong. But I don't use IDEs much so I don't really know the correct way. I would delete the IDE metadata and rebuild the project from the code you have.

Comment: I also think the project is borked in some way - the `venv` dir is listed under the content root, but not present in the project tree...

Comment: I've tried recreating the project several times and nothing changes. It doesn't show in the project tree because Excluded files are filtered.